# App Permission requests

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to create a 2013 workflow that uses an App step to break inheritance on a form library and give individual forms unique permissions. I am having problems, and constantly receiving **"Unauthorized"** Status from my Http calls.

I think the problem is in my App Permissions. What is this "Content" word they are using? Am I literally placing content in the URI?

```
  <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest   Scope="http://domain/content/sites/workflows/" Right="FullControl"/>
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Is this the correct way? Or is `"/sites"` unnecessary since the site collection is different in the content URI? should it just be "`domain/content/workflows"`?

This should give permissions to the whole site collection. So can I use subsite libraries and still break permissions and set my own?

Comment: Please check this [APP Permissions Request XML - Elevate Workflow Permissions in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the scope you want to use for your AppPermissionRequest is "http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" (I've successfully used this for Workflow app steps in the past). Note that you want to use this literal string and *not* replace any of it with URLs from your SharePoint farm.

"Content" refers to your content database.

Table 1 at this MSDN article describes the four different scopes you can use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx

Your choices are:

- http://sharepoint/content/tenant
- http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection
- http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web
- http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list

From the article: "Because permission requests are made without information about the topology of the site collection where the app is installed, the scope is expressed as a type instead of as the URL of a specific instance. These scope types are expressed as URIs. Permissions to resources that are stored in the SharePoint content database are organized under the following URI: http://sharepoint/content."

Comment: I think I get it thanks. Just to clarify, I'm using the site collection APP Id, and adding http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection

Comment: The full permissions string you want to use is `<AppPermissionRequests><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/></AppPermissionRequests>`

Comment: The App ID depends on if you're deploying an app of your own or if you're just trying to use an App step in a 2013 workflow that you're creating in SharePoint designer.